# Cryptic signs in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, utf

(please excuse my bad english)

i have a problem with a page of my customer. I created a Shop with WP and Woocommerce. You can visit it here: http://www.hopfenhexe.de/

My problem: when you add an article to the cart, go to checkout, fill all fields and press "weiter" (confirm button) some cryptic symbols appear on top of the adress fields.
These symbols should say "Please check your order and confirm..." (in german).

What is this? How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!
Mon

Comment: I would start with standard troubleshooting procedures... switching to a default theme, disabling plugins and re-enabling them one by one to see if you can isolate the problem. Make sure everything is updated. Maybe even re-upload clean versions of everything, because I can't say for sure if you were hacked, but that is super strange.

Comment: it looks like there's a problem with the non-english characters in the POST. Your encoding must be incorrect; Try to set all the encoding to UTF8 for woocommerce and wordpress

Comment: is there a specific place in wordpress where I can switch everything in utf8? or do i have to isolate the buggy plugin and type it in these files?